# HTTPD - No Path For Address

Tags: php, macos, apache, httpd.conf

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days on this one. Running this on Mac OSX Version 10.12.6

When I run `apachectl restart`

I immediately see in my system.log several entires of the following:

```
httpd[89474]: no path for address 0x1145b3000
```

I've installed everything with homebrew, and can confirm that brew doctor returns no issues, and that all formulae are up to date. If I throw a `die('1');` in my code, I am echoed the 1, however when trying to run the application I get the same no path for address error.

I've verified that PHP is parsing correctly as I can run code and echo out the result when exiting the application. I've also verified that this is somehow related to a custom vhost, as removing my vhosts allows me to execute a basic request to a `phpinfo();` file.

Nothing is logged in either the base apache error log, or my error logs defined in the application vhosts. When trying to run the application I get an immediate 500 error with a blank response and no error logs.

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: are you 100% certain that the apache running is the one you brewed, or could it be the 'brain dead' osx distro version ? `which httpd` in command line.

Comment: which httpd returns `/usr/local/bin/httpd`
whch apachectl returns `/usr/local/bin/apachectl`
and which php returns `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: `ls -al /usr/local/bin/http` should be a simlink to Cellar.  Also `httpd -v` should be the right version as the simlinked one.

Comment: `httpd -> ../Cellar/httpd24/2.4.27/bin/httpd`

`httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 18 2017 13:30:24`
`/usr/local/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 18 2017 13:30:24`

Comment: ich ... gonna be tricky that.  `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` should presented you the 'post parse' view of the vhost files. Maybe you can spot an anomaly in there.

Comment: Everything looks normal from what I can see.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CK3rWshR

Comment: far fetched : any SMB mounted devices, of some samba sharing enabled ?

Comment: also, if you installed this mac from an older one (via TimeMachine), and this is Sierra, you may have to remove hombrew altogether and reinstall it.

Comment: No SMB mounted devices, and this did not come from TimeMachine.

Comment: i meant : was homebrew installed prior to an OS update ? if yes, you could try removing it altogether and reinstalling it (and all your bottles). I know, long shot, but someone reported that helped.

Comment: What's in the Listen directive?

Comment: @ezra-s can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Xenology just a wild guess to see if it was somehow related to the ip address and not memory. Listen directive in httpd tells httpd which ip it should listen to, not virtualhosts. I'm quite ignorant regarding OSX at the moment, but I guess it does not hurt to ask.